# ORACLE - insert records by multiple user on PK table

Tags: oracle

In oracle I have a table say `EMPLOYEE(EMPID,EMPNAME)` with primary key on `EMPID`.

Two users are having insert privileges to this table say `USER1` and `USER2`.

`User1` insert a record with `EMPID=1 and EMPNAME='XYZ'` and not committed. But if `USER2` is trying to insert the same record `EMPID=1 and EMPNAME='XYZ'` then the screen get hangs till `user1` commits or rollback.

Is there option to insert this record by both the users with out any hang and the user who commits second should get the PK violation error.

Thanks,
Niju Jose

Comment: The second should not get a PK violation error because there is not PK violation. A PK violation can happen, after the first one has ***committed***.

Answer (score 0):

In a single-user database, the user can modify data in the database without concern for other users modifying the same data at the same time. However, in a multiuser database, the statements within multiple simultaneous transactions can update the same data. Transactions executing at the same time need to produce meaningful and consistent results.

```
Isolation Level     Dirty Read      Nonrepeatable Read      Phantom Read
----------------    ------------    ------------------      -------------
Read uncommitted    Possible        Possible                Possible
Read committed      Not possible    Possible                Possible
Repeatable read     Not possible    Not possible            Possible
Serializable        Not possible    Not possible            Not possible
```

In your case, Oracle acquires a row level lock. The insert case is simpler, because inserted rows are locked, but also are not seen by other users because they are not commited. When the user commits, he also releases the locks, so, other users can view these rows, update them, or delete them.

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm) about Data concurrency and consistency.
Also see here more details on [Insert Mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251695/database-insert-mechanism)

To explain more, I reproduce [Florin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319875/florin-ghita) answer here

For example, let be tableA(col1 number, col2 number), with this data within it:

```
col1  |  col2
1     |  10
2     |  20
3     |  30
```

If user John issues at `time1`:

```
update tableA set col2=11 where col1=1;
```

will lock row1.

At `time2` user Mark issue an

```
update tableA set col2=22 where col1=2;
```

the update will work, because the row 2 is not locked.

Now the table looks in database:

```
col1  |  col2
1     |  11   --locked by john
2     |  22   --locked by mark  
3     |  30
```

For Mark table is(he does not see the changes uncommited)

```
col1  |  col2
1     |  10   
2     |  22   
3     |  30
```

For John table is:(he does not see the changes uncommited)

```
col1  |  col2
1     |  11   
2     |  20   
3     |  30
```

If mark tries at `time3`:

```
update tableA set col2=12 where col1=1;
```

his session will hang until `time4` when John will issue an `commit`.(Rollback will also unlock the rows, but changes will be lost)

table is(in db, at time4):

```
col1  |  col2
1     |  11   
2     |  22   --locked by mark  
3     |  30
```

Immediatley, after John's commit, the row1 is unlocked and marks's update will do the job:

```
col1  |  col2
1     |  12   --locked by mark  
2     |  22   --locked by mark  
3     |  30
```

lets's mark issue a rollbak at time5:

```
col1  |  col2
1     |  11   
2     |  20   
3     |  30
```

**So your hang is due to the fact that the Oracle engine is waiting for a commit or a rollback from User1, before giving a definitive response to user2.**